# Monitor warm-up flickering issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I asked this question on the Hardware Recommendations forum, which I have been informed was the wrong place. The mod recommended I post here.

I have been struggling with this issue for 3 months +.

My PC decided to auto upgrade to Windows 10 overnight, without permission. Since then I have had problems with one of my 2 monitors flickering.

Before you all ask, YES I have trawled the internet and tried many solutions, most related to Error Reporting services which I have disabled.

Anyway, the monitor flickers (strobes) initially rapidly then decreasing over a period of approx. 30-40 seconds and then stops. This ONLY happens after it has been sleeping for a reasonable time or the monitor has auto switched off.

It does NOT happen when manually switching off the monitor and then back on shortly afterwards. However, if the monitor is switched off overnight it does have the same problem.

So this seems to be a time / warm-up related issue ... maybe. The monitor is connected using an HDMI to DVI cable. The other monitor, connected via standard VGA is fine.

Occasionally, the monitor comes on flickering AND dim when woken and, in these circumstances, it will flicker as before for 40-50 secs and then go blank. I then need to turn the monitor off and on again and it will start flickering again as previously stated. I only ever need to do this once.

After either of these start up scenarios the monitor works perfectly, until it sleeps again!!

VERY , very weird.

PLEASE help before I go out of my mind!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it happened shortly after upgrading to Windows 10, you may want to ensure your graphics adapter drivers are up to date and try different resolutions and refresh rates to see if you can improve the situation, hoping to prolong its short life expectancy.

The fact that it is strictly related to the monitor's warm up indicates that this is a problem with the monitor itself.

If it's still under warranty, contact the manufacturer.  Otherwise you should start budgeting for a new one.